# Synchronous call using wrapAsync

Tags: javascript, meteor

I wrote a piece of code to get CSS contents from a file and I want to get that data inside my helper function.

Server-side:

```
Meteor.methods({

    'getCSS': function(filename) {
        return '<style>' + Assets.getText('css/' + filename) + '</style>';
    }

});
```

The `css` folder is located inside a `private` folder and consists of CSS files required for several pages. To my knowledge, the server-side code works correctly.

Client-side:

```
Template.home.helpers({

    'css': function() {

        var asyncFn = function(fn, cb) {
            Meteor.call('getCSS', fn, function(err, res) {
                console.log(res);   // prints data correctly
                cb && cb(null, res);
            });
        }
        var syncFn = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncFn);
        var result = syncFn('home.css');
        console.log(result);    // undefined
        return result;

    }

});
```

After researching about how to use `Meteor.wrapAsync` this is the best solution that I could come up with. Not sure what I missed. I followed instructions from [this](http://phucnguyen.info/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-async-meteor/) blog.

Comment: Is there a question here?  What are you asking? What's the goal? What's not working?

Comment: Though there is no error thrown, the CSS fails to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Meteor.wrapAsync` on the client, because on the server the illusion of synchronicity depends on [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) and there is no such parallel on the client.

Fibers effectively inlines asynchronous functions so that other code can run while waiting for the callback. Among other things, it helps eliminate the [callback pyramid of doom](http://callbackhell.com/) anti-pattern. However, it does make it harder to reason about your code since if Javascript objects are shared between fibers, you'll have to explicitly think about when your code might be yielding (voluntarily pre-empted, such as by making a database call).

In any case, it will probably be a while before something similar becomes available on the client - as you can see, Fibers is implemented as a C++ package for node and can't be done simply with Javascript, since it actually makes asynchronous function calls look synchronous.

In your case, the proper way of doing lazy loading of CSS (as opposed to just including it in the rest of the Meteor bundle) is to just put it in the `public/` folder (or include from a package with `{isAsset: true}`) and use a `<head>` tag to load when you need it.

Comment: That's a wonderful explanation, and thanks for the suggesting alternative methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve here.

From my point of view, cas should be load and compile from the first loading. Don't think it is a good idea to load CSS on the fly... You'll not be able to unload.

If you're inside a tracker computation (i.e. into router for example, on rendered events) you could use ReactiveMethod package to have something like synchronous call. It use the tracker dependency to wait response.

Another thing, you could finally setup a server side route to served CSS files from private folder...

Here if you need it,

Cheers

Comment: My goal is to selectively load CSS files for each template. If I put a CSS file in a folder other than `private` it will be loaded during all templates, so I will face a restriction in using `id` and `class` names.

Comment: You will still face a restriction because you will not be able to un-load CSS when you render other templates. There are only rare cases when you'd actually want to lazy load CSS, such as for optimizing load times. JVercout is right and you may want to reconsider what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the return value in a local variable, I used a Session. Now it works!

```
Template.home.helpers({

    'css': function() {

        Meteor.call('getCSS', 'home.css', function(err, res) {
            Session.set('css', res);
        });
        return Session.get('css');

    }

});
```